# possibility to use SQL file in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sql file which was created before, and I want to be able to search in it only with basic `SELECT FROM WHERE commands`. I cannot find any appropriate source or tutorial, I don't know even where to put file.

I want my program to have a `Spinner` and `EditText` and a `Button`. When I choose a selection or enter a text and click the button, query will be created with this entries.

Is it possible?

Comment: Here's your official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html. Good luck with learning on how to use Google ;)!

Comment: There are lots of tutorials/example available already. Just search **Use existing database in android**

Comment: Thank you for your responses but I saw those, but I read that sql and sqlite files are completely different. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below tutorial

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

And keep your db file in assests folder

And you can use below code in databasehelper file for fetching details

```
public ContactModel getUser(int userid) {
    ContactModel user = new ContactModel();
    openDataBase();
    Cursor c;

    String select = "Select * from contactMaster " + "where Id =" + userid;
    try {
        c = myDataBase.rawQuery(select, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            c.moveToNext();

            user.setId(c.getInt(0));
            user.setName(c.getString(1));
            user.setPhone(c.getString(2));

        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        myDataBase.close();
        SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: this is quiet good tutorial which I have encountered before but I am not allowed to make any changes in sql file. So can I use my .sql file fully without any changes?

Comment: I have tried using mysql files directly keeping in assests folder and that works.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I cannot complete my duty but progressed some. 

But I see I have to work on database usage on android more, a lot more.